# I get this error when uploading my app: Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK than version code 1

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, build.gradle, google-play-console

I have an app on google play store. Currently there's only one upload.

And I want to upload a new version, but when ever I do that this error shows:

> Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1

No matter weather it is versioncode 1, 2 or 3. The first release way versioncode 1, and this is versioncode 2.

I don't know what the problem is, maybe I have to sync the build.gradle, I've heard some ppl talk about that, but I am not 100% sure how to?

Also If I make a new 'App' and upload it there this error doesn't show op, that's probably because on that 'app' there's no other app-release with that name, or any with higher.

Also, there's like 300 different build.gradle files, the one I am talking about is the one under the directory

```
ApplicatioName\myApplication\build.gradle
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

What do I do?

Comment: Very naïve of me to ask, but sometimes the simplest things are the culprits: Did you recreate the APK after you changed the version code?

Comment: _"ApplicatioName\myApplication\build.gradle"_ Typically the `build.gradle` where you modify this setting would be in a subdirectory named `app`.

Comment: what was versionName on versionCode 1 ?

Comment: @lucidbrot Yea I did do that a lot :)

Comment: @Michael oh, yea I just opened that file, I do not find 'versionName'/'versionCode'. Bu there's something called FlutterVersionName = '2.0' And FlutterVersionCode = '4'. Do I change those, or and if so, why is the versioncode 4, and versionname 2 by default?

Comment: @UlaşKasım I'm not sure you've understood, the error says that I already have an apk/aab file with versioncode 1, but I've changed it, at least in the build.gradle at "ApplicatioName\myApplication\build.gradle" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flutter, at least in my experience, you don't need to modify version codes anywhere but in `pubspec.yaml`. Say your `version` tag there is `version: 1.0.0+1`, your android version code will be 1 and your user visible version name is 1.0.0. You can change this to `version: 1.1.0+2`, for example, and that should fix your problem.

Edit: And, obviously, rebuild.

Comment: Thx a whole lot, it worked :) It was that simple, yet I had never heard of it before,  somehow none of my thousands of google searches had answered this, and it was just what I needed :) Thx